# JavaScript do stuff every % row

Tags: javascript, math, modulus

I wan't to return a css class from a javascript function every %th number.
It has something to do with modulus, could never figure out exact expressions.

"i" variable begins with 0

Example:

i = 0 returns red

i = 3 return darkcyan

i = 5 returns darkorange

i = 7 returns blue

1 = 15 returns darkorange

```
// Get CSS class
var getClass = function(i) {

    // Every 0sth 
    if () {
        return 'red';

    // Every 1th number
    } else if () {
        return 'blue';

    // Every 2th number
    } else if () {
        return  'magenta';

    // Every 3th number
    } else if () {
        return 'darkcyan';

    // Every 4th number
    } else if () {
        return 'mediumorchid';

    // Every 5th number
    } else if () {
        return 'darkorange';

    // Else
    } else {
        return 'red';
    }
}
```

Comment: "every fourth number" is a subset of "every second number". If you meant "every second number out of n", there's no zeroth number out of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that it has to do with the remainder operator (`%`):

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'magenta', 'darkcyan', 'mediumorchid', 'darkorange'];
var color = colors[index % colors.length];
```

...where `index` is your value that goes from `0` on up.

**Live Example:**

```js
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'magenta', 'darkcyan', 'mediumorchid', 'darkorange'];
var color, index;
for (var index = 0; index < 30; ++index) {
    color = colors[index % colors.length];
    console.log(index + " => " + color);
}
```

Comment: OK, you understood the question, but you get to admit that, worded as is, the question doesn't exactly make sense, right?

Comment: @JanDvorak: To me it was clear enough, but I can see what you mean now you mention it. English is definitely not the OP's first language.